# Indexing values in another array using a list of tuples

Tags: python, sorting, loops, numpy, indexing

Hi I want to use the values in another array using a list of tuples as the index's

Code :

```
import numpy as np

elevation_array = np.random.rand(5,5) #creates a random array 5 by 5

sort_idx = np.argsort(elevation_array, axis=None)

new_idx = zip(*np.unravel_index(sort_idx[::-1], elevation_array.shape))

for r, c in new_idx:
    r, c = [r, c]
for [x, y], elevation in np.ndenumerate(elevation_array):
    print elevation[r, c] # I will want to for other stuff here later on
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
for r, c in new_idx:
    r, c = [r, c]
    for elevation in np.ndenumerate(elevation_array):
        print elevation[r, c]
```

I get the error in the first of:

```
IndexError: 0-d arrays can only use a single () or a list of newaxes (and a single ...) as an index
```

Any help would be great and explaination would be really useful as I am new to python

In the 2nd I get the error:

```
tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

**ANSWER:**

```
for r, c in new_idx:
    print elevation_array[r, c]
```

I got it so simple I can't believe I did not know how to do that! :)

Comment: What exactly causes your error? All the code that you printed runs fine for me.

Comment: Appologies I didnt put the code which give the error. I want the elevation_array to printed out in order from the highest value to the lowest value these are stored within the new_idx array as indexs. Does this make sense?

Comment: Change `elevation[r, c]` with `elevation_array[r, c]`. `elevation` is a scalar, not an array, hence it cannot be indexed.

Comment: @Jamie doing that seems prints out an entire array of each value? e.g 25x the highest number, then 25 x the next highest number etc...

Comment: I think I did it! WOO!

Comment: I don't think the line `r, c = [r, c]` does anything.  That simply takes the `r` and `c` you already have, makes a list containing them, and then sets `r` to the first element of the list and `c` to the second element of the list-- which is what they were to begin with.

Comment: @DSM you would be correct

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same result doing:

```
print np.sort(elevation_array.flat)[::-1]
```